# Find all the points $(a,b)$ on the curve $C$ given by $y=3x^2+2$ So that the tangent lines to $C$ pass through $(-1,-7)$b

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My guess is that we need the slope of the lines that are tangent to the curve need to equal the derivative of the function at the point.

$f'(x)= 6x = 6a$

$m(x) = \frac{\bigtriangleup y}{\bigtriangleup x} = \frac{-7-b}{-1-a}$

Set up $$6a(-1-a)=-7-b$$
$$-6a-6a^2=-7-b$$

Am I on the right track? If not what is wrong?

Comment: As an alternative method, find the intersections of C with the polar line of the point, $(y+7)/2=-3x+2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method you could use is the following: let $(a,b)$ be a point on the curve $y=3x^2+2.$ The tangent is $6x$ and, if it passes through $(-1,-7),$ it must have the same slope as the line joining the point at which the tangent meets the curve to the point $(-1,-7).$ Thus we want to solve the equation

$\dfrac{3a^2+2+7}{a+1}=6a\Rightarrow 3a^2+9=6a^2+6a\\\Rightarrow 3a^2+6a-9=0\Rightarrow 3(a+3)(a-1)=0\Rightarrow a=-3 $

or $a=1.$

Thus, the points $(a,b)$ are $(-3,29)$ and $(1,5).$ Since the slope of any tangent line to the curve is $6x,$ the equation of the tangent lines are $y-29=-18(x+3)\Rightarrow \boxed{y=-18x-25}$ and $y-5=6(x-1)\Rightarrow \boxed{y=6x-1}.$

Comment: wait how did you derive $(-3,29)$?

Comment: I got the values of $a$ and used the fact that $b=3a^2+2$ since $(a,b)$ is on $y=3x^2+2$.

Comment: Okay I follow that but then where did you get $y-5=6(x-1)$ Like plugging in the values of a only gives you the y-coordinates $5,29$

Comment: I still need to derive 1 and -3

Comment: Ok, so let me explain things simply. $1$ and $-3$ are solutions to the quadratic. They should be easy to derive. I used the fact that the slope is $6a$ and the slope-intercept form to get $y-5=6(x-1)$ and $y-29=-18(x+3).$ I edited my solution just to make things a little clearer.

Comment: All makes total sense now

Answer (score 2):

You have $f'(x)= 6x$ so that at $x=a$, we have $f'(a)=6a$. Then using the point slope formula,
$$
y-b= 6a(x- a)
$$
Then $y=6ax-6a^2+b$. Now use the fact that $(a,b)$ is on the curve $y= 3x^2+2$, so $b= 3a^2+2$ and the line $y=6ax-6a^2+b$ contains the point $(-1,-7)$ so $-7=6a(-1)-6a^2+b$ so $6a^2+6a-b=7$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: it looks like a quadratic

Comment: but no I cannot take it from there

Comment: @K.Gibson https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+6a%5E2%2B6a-b%3D7+and+b%3D3a%5E2%2B2

Answer (score 2):

Let the slope of the tangent line be $m$

The line passing through $(-1,-7)$ with slope of $m$ has the equation $$y=m(x+1)-7$$

For the tangency we need the line and the curve intersect at only one point, which means the equation  $$3x^2+2=m(x+1)-7$$

has a root of multiplicity $2$

The equation simplifies to $$3x^2-mx-m+9=0=$$ and for the double root we need $$m^2-12(9-m)=0$$

which results in $m=6$ or $m=-18$

That is the equation of tangent lines are $$y=6x-1$$ and $$y=-18x-25$$

Points of tangency are $(1,5)$ and $(-3,29)$

Comment: how did you get from 3x^2 to m^2?

Comment: @K.Gibson  In order for a quadratic equation to have double roots you have to have $b^2-4ac=0$ that gives you the $ m^2 $ stuff.

Comment: how can I find the values $-3,29$

Comment: @K.Gibson Solve the equation $ 3x^2+2 = 6x-1$ to get $x=1$. Solve $3x^2+2=-18x-25$ to get $x=-3$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The pencil of lines through $(-1,-7)$ has equation $$y+7=m(x+1)\quad (m\in\mathbf R).$$
Write the quadratic equation with parameter $m$ which determines the abscissæ of the intersection points of the line and the parabola. The line is tangent to the parabola if and only if this equation has a double root.

Answer (score 1):

Here equation of tangent will be given by y-2=mx-$m^2$/12

Now put (-1,-7) we get m=- 18 , 6

For equation in general form  refer ::  https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/equation-of-tangent-to-parabola/